# Como encontrar archivos cuyo nombre no es exacto en python

Tags: python, archivo

cree un script para buscar las imagenes que tengan los codigos que esten en un archivo excel y copiarlas en otra carpeta.

Por ejemplo en mi archivo excel tengo 1856.jpg, 532.jpg etc.

En la carpeta que especifico, tengo esas imagenes y hasta ese punto el programa funciona y copia lo que este en el archivo de excel.

El problema llega cuando mi excel manda a buscar por ejemplo la imagen 674.jpg entonces en mi carpeta la tengo pero de esta forma 456_674_542.jpg es decir en una sola foto hay 3 codigos, como le hago en ese caso?

```
 ​import​ ​os​, ​shutil​, ​xlrd 
  
 ​#creamos una lista vacia para almacenar los codigos posteriormente 
 ​files_to_find​ ​=​ [] 
 ​lista_imagenes_total​=​[] 
 ​ruta_destino​ ​=​ ​'C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Pictures/carpeta4'​ ​#'input("Digite la ruta de la carpeta destino: ") 
  
 ​#Abrimos el archivo excel y cargamos todos los codigos en la lista vacia. 
 ​data​ ​=​ ​xlrd​.​open_workbook​(​input​(​"Digite el nombre del archivo excel y su extension: "​)) 
 ​sheet1​ ​=​ ​data​.​sheet_by_index​(​0​) 
 ​for​ ​i​ ​in​ ​range​(​sheet1​.​nrows​): 
 ​    ​files_to_find​.​append​(​sheet1​.​cell_value​(​i​, ​0​)) 
 ​     
 ​#Buscamos los codigos en esta ruta 
 ​for​ ​root​, ​dirs​, ​files​ ​in​ ​os​.​walk​(​'C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Desktop/FOTOS PRODUCTOS/'​): 
 ​    ​for​ ​_file​ ​in​ ​files​: 
 ​        ​if​ ​_file​ ​in​ ​files_to_find​: 
 ​            ​print​ (​f'​{​_file​}​ Encontrado en esta ruta: '​ ​+​ ​str​(​root​)) ​# Si lo encontramos nos dira que fue encontrado en esta ruta 
 ​            ​shutil​.​copy​(​os​.​path​.​abspath​(​root​ ​+​ ​'/'​ ​+​ ​_file​), ​'C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Pictures/carpeta4'​) 
 ​        ​lista_imagenes_total​.​append​(​_file​) 
  
 ​#Verificamos cuales archivos no fueron encontrados y lo imprimimos 
 ​for​ ​elementos​ ​in​ ​files_to_find​: 
 ​    ​if​ ​elementos​ ​not​ ​in​ ​lista_imagenes_total​: 
 ​        ​print​(​f"El archivo ​{​elementos​}​ no fue encontrado!"​)
```

Comment: Tienes que definir un criterio de "similitud".

Comment: @CandidMoe ¿a qué te refieres con criterio de similud? podrías dar un ejemplo o explicar algo. No encontré ese concepto

Comment: En Excel tienes los archivos 456.jpg, 674.jpg, y 542.jpg. El disco me encuentro con el  archivo 456_674_542.jpg. ¿A cual de los tres archivos es similar? ¿Es 123456789.jpg similar a 456.jpg?

Comment: En resumen, necesitas una función `simil(arch1, arch2)` que retorne True si ambos archivos son "similares" y False en otro caso.